# Different class types of a same template interacting with each other

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, wrapper

I am wondering if the following is possible.
Lets say I have a code like this:

```
template <class NumberType>
struct Number
{
   NumberType value;

   void operator = (Number in_val)
   {
        value = in_val;
   }
}
```

So then I would be able to do something like:

```
Number<int> n1, n2;
n2.value = 5;
n1 = n2;
cout << "Value: " << n1.value << endl;
```

But this won't allow me to do the following:

```
Number<int> n1;
Number<double> n2;
n2.value = 5;
n1 = n2;
cout << "Value: " << n1.value << endl;
```

How to make this possible? 
Do I have to wrap this struct/class with another OR do I have to make some fancy recursion?

p.s. 
I have used C++ for some time now but never tried `templates`. So consider that I'm very new to templates.

-- EDIT --
Ok I got it correctly now. But another related question came.

```
template<class OtherNumType>
Number& operator *= ( const OtherNumType& in_value)
{
    value *= in_value;
    return *this;
}
```

This gives a compilation error. Why? What is the correct way?

Comment: For the new content (after edit), it would be better to post a new question. (However, I think the reason why compilation fails is related to the type you use for `OtherNumType`. If that is a `Number<T>` for some `T`, you must change the function definition to `value *= in_value.value`.)

Comment: What's the error you get? (Or have you posted a separate question?)

Comment: `binary '*=' : no global operator found which takes type 'NumberVector2D<NumberType>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` , but now it worked. I saw my fault. I was trying to do `n1 *= 3` and it works. :) but cant do `n1 *= n2`. Now i see my fault. sorry for the false alarm. i should overload the operator to support this with a parameter type `Number<OtherNumberType>`. Now i understand. Thank you sir. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the template definition of `Number<T>` is considered by the compiler for any specific type `T`, the name `Number` (when used as a type name) is interpreted as `Number<T>`, whatever `T` may be at that point.

Hence, for `Number<int>`, your current template definition provides only for the assignment operator below:

```
void operator=(Number<int> in_val)
```

because `Number` is interpreted as `Number<int>` at that point.

In order to make the operator more flexible, you can turn it into a member template (a templated function in an already templated class):

```
template <class NumberType>
struct Number
{
  NumberType value;

  template <typename T2>
  Number &operator=(const Number<T2> &in_val)
  {
    value = in_val.value;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Note how I have modified the operator not only to accept `Number<T2>` for *any type* `T2`, but also make it return `*this` and accept the argument as const reference – that is the most common and useful way to define the assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you for all the info. I have seen this kind of implementation (without the template thing) of the assignment operator in many places and also used this sometimes blindly. I understand why we return the saved value and why the "const" keyword is used. But i always wondered why we are returning this value as a reference. Would that be a bad thing? i mean if someone takes it in as pointer and change it, it would change the value inside the object, rite? this should be a separate question. but if u have any link, i will go there an learn :) Thankw very much to all of you :)

Comment: @Deamonpog We don't return the saved value; we return `*this`, a reference to the current object. The reason we do this by reference, rather than pointer, is that it makes it easy to make the assignment operation part of a chain of operations, e.g. if you have objects `Number<int> n1,n2`, you can do something like this: `if ((n1 = f(x)) == n2)`. I.e. you make an assignment (of the result of `f(x)` to `n1`) and then immediately use it in a comparison (to `n2`). Had we returned a pointer, we would have to dereference it, and our code would be less intuitive.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I meant was that someone can do a thing like `Number<int> * p = &(n1 = f(x));` rite?

Comment: Yes, sure. Since we return a reference, you can do that.

Comment: @Deamonpog: It is very rare to see RAW pointers in modern C++ code.

Comment: @Deamonpog Now that I read your comment again, I understand what you actually meant (I think). You are right: By returning a reference, we enable the caller to manipulate the object, including taking its address. But the object must have been available to the caller anyway already (otherwise, the assignment operator, which is non-const, couldn't have been called). So I don't think the reference we return enables the caller to do anything that wasn't possible anyway.

Comment: Ya thats what i meant, and you are rite. Now I got into another question which is related. I will edit the question and put it there. thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a template operator=

```
template<class OtherNumType>
Number<NumberType>& operator= ( const Number<OtherNumType>& in_val)
{
    value = in_val.value; // ok if the number types are implicitly convertable
    return *this;
}
```